# Cardinality of a set of countable connected Hausdorff spaces

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

It is a [non-trivial result](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9.pdf) that there is a countable connected Hausdorff space.

Let ${\cal T}$ be a set of connected Hausdorff topologies on $\omega$ such that whenever $\tau_1\neq\tau_2\in {\cal T}$ we have $(\omega,\tau_1)\not\cong (\omega,\tau_2)$. What is the largest cardinality that ${\cal T}$ can have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the number of such topologies is $2^{\mathfrak c}$. Such (huge) number of connected Hausdorff topologies can be constructed by a suitable modification of the [Bing's construction](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9.pdf) of a connected Hausdorff space.

First we introduce the necessary definitions. A subset $U$ of the real line is called *regular open* if $U$ coincides with the interior of the closure of $U$ in $\mathbb R$.

A filter $\mathcal F$ on $\mathbb R$ will be called

$\bullet$ (*regular*) *open* if $\mathcal F$ has a base consisting of (regular) open subsets of $\mathbb R$;

$\bullet$ *vanishing* if each neighborhood of zero in $\mathbb R$ belongs to $\mathcal F$.

It can be shown that the set of regular open vanishing filters on $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

For any open vanishing filter $\mathcal F$ we define a countable connected Hausdorff space $X_{\mathcal F}$ as follows. On the countable set $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q:y\ge 0\}$ consider the topology $\tau_{\mathcal F}$ in which a neighborhood base at a point $(x,y)\in X$ consists of the sets 
$$\Delta_U=\{(x,y)\}\cup\{(t,0)\in X:t\in (x-\sqrt{3}y+U)\cup(x+\sqrt{3}y+U)\}$$where $U\in\mathcal F$.

It can be shown that the topological space $X_{\mathcal F}$ is Hausdorff and the closures of any non-empty open sets in  $X_{\mathcal F}$ have a common point, which implies that $X_{\mathcal F}$ is connected.

It can be shown that for distinct regular open vanishing filters  $\mathcal U,\mathcal V$ the topologies $\tau_{\mathcal U}$, $\tau_{\mathcal V}$ on the set $X$ are distinct, which implies that on the countable set $X$ there exist $2^{\mathfrak c}$ Hausdorff connected topologies. Since the cardinality of bijections of the set $X$ is continuum, the number of pairwise non-homeomorphic connected Hausdorff topologies on $X$ remains equal to $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

Comment: Amazing! - I would already have been surprised if the number of such topologies were "only" $2^{\aleph_0}$!

Comment: It is very nice, but, unfortunately, does not provide invariants which may distinguish such spaces.

Answer (score 5):

That there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ homeomorphism types of countably infinite connected Hausdorff spaces is already proved in

> Kannan, V.; Rajagopalan, M.
>   Regularity and dispersion in countable spaces.
>   Duke Math. J. 39 (1972), 729–734.

There are certainly no more than $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ homeomorphism types of countably infinite topological spaces, so "the largest cardinality" is $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

In fact the authors prove a bit more.  I quote from [F. Burton Jones'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._Burton_Jones) Math Review, taken from MathSciNet:

> A regular Hausdorff space (with more than one point) cannot be both connected and countable. A separation axiom weaker than regularity (but stronger than Hausdorff) is Uryson's: If $p$ and $q$ are distinct points, there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $p \in U$, $q \in V$ and $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} = \varnothing$. Countable connected Uryson spaces have been known for some time, but only recently P. Roy has given an example [same J. 33 (1966), 331–333; MR0196701] of a countable connected Uryson space with a dispersion point, i.e., a point whose complement is totally disconnected. Roy's space is regular at only one point, and he raised the question whether such a space can be regular almost everywhere. The authors supply such an example. In fact, they show that there exist $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ mutually non-homeomorphic, countable, connected Uryson spaces with dispersion points, each of which is regular at each point of a dense subset. In order to carry through their construction, the authors characterize the countable, totally disconnected, Hausdorff spaces that admit a regular dispersion point, i.e., those that may be made connected by the addition of a single point at which the space becomes regular.

With regard to Fedor Petrov's comment:

> It is very nice, but, unfortunately, does not provide invariants which may distinguish such spaces.

Indeed it seems difficult in practice to sort countably connected Hausdorff spaces into homeomorphism types!  In Section 3 of [this paper with Lebowitz-Lockard and Pollack](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/CLLP_November_30_2017.pdf) we associate to every countably infinite integral domain $R$ with zero Jacobson radical -- hence in particular to every countably infinite principal ideal domain (PID) with infinitely many prime ideals -- a countably infinite, connected Hausdorff "Golomb space" $G(R)$.  The number of isomorphism types of countably infinite PIDs with infinitely many prime ideals is easily seen to be $\mathfrak{c}$ (which is also the number of isomorphism types of countably infinite rings).  So one may hope that we are producing $\mathfrak{c}$ homeomorphism types of countably infinite connected Hausdorff spaces via this algebraic construction...but it is of course conceivable that $G(R)$ and $G(S)$ are homeomorphic when $R$ and $S$ are not isomorphic.  Does this ever happen?  **We don't know.**  In our first draft of the paper we could prove nothing about this, but later we were able to show that if 
$\mathbb{F}_1$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$ are finite fields and $G(\mathbb{F}_1[t])$ and $G(\mathbb{F}_2[t])$ are homeomorphic then $\# \mathbb{F}_1 = \# \mathbb{F}_2$, which shows that these spaces fall into at least $\aleph_0$ homeomorphism types.

In order to show this we adapt work of [T. Banakh, J. Mioduszewski and S. Turek](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06749).  Many of the key ideas first appeared in [a MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285557/is-the-golomb-countable-connected-space-topologically-rigid) of [Taras Banakh](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/bancv.html).

Comment: Very interesting! Does not this work with complements of Jacobson radicals in more general domains?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I suspect not.  At least the proof of (i) $\implies$ (ii) in Theorem 5 does not immediately carry over.  In particular there will be distinct elements $x$ and $y$ not in the Jacobson radical, but such that $x-y$ is in the Jacobson radical, and this look problematic.