# Is the Golomb countable connected space topologically rigid?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids

The [Golomb space](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/700933/Toposym_01-1961-1_41.pdf) $\mathbb G$ is the set of positive integers endowed with the topology generated by the base consisting of the arithmetic progressions $a+b\mathbb N_0$ with relatively prime $a,b$ and $\mathbb N_0=\{0\}\cup\mathbb N$. It is known that the space $\mathbb G$ is connected and Hausdorff.

It is also easy to check that the multiplication map $\cdot:\mathbb G\times \mathbb G\to\mathbb G$, $\cdot:(x,y)\mapsto xy$, is continuous, so $\mathbb G$ is a commutative topological semigroup.

> **Problem.** Is the Golomb space $\mathbb G$ topologically homogeneous? Or maybe rigid?

We recall that a topological space $X$ is *rigid* if its homeomorphism group is trivial.

This problem was motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46986/countable-connected-hausdorff-space), which discusses the relation of the Golomb space to another countable connected Hausdorff space, called the rational projective space $\mathbb QP^\infty$. This space is easily seen to be topologically homogeneous.

Comment: Do you know if it has a single non-trivial self-homeomorphism?

Comment: @YCor No I do not know such a homeomorphism. What is very pityis that I have thought on the problem of homogeneity of the Golomb space about 10 years ago and remember that I proved that 1 is a fixed point of any homeomorphism of $\mathbb G$, which implies that $\mathbb G$ is not topologically homogeneous. But now I cannot find any notes with that proof and also do not remember the idea of the proof :(

Comment: It's a lovely question! Do you think your former argument could possibly have carried from $1$ to $2$, and so on..?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen No if I remember truly, 1 is a special number and the argument does not work for other numbers. Maybe prime number can go to other prime numbers, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Edit, Dec 6, 2019] I have a pleasure to inform that this problem was finally resolved in affirmative by [T.Banakh, D.Spirito and S.Turek](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01994) who proved the following

> **Theorem.** *The Golomb space is topologically rigid.*

Edit: now published: The Golomb space is topologically rigid. Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. 62 (2021), no. 3, 347–360.

Comment: The initial answer contained a sketch of proof that 1 is fixed by any self-homeomorphism, and contained much more mathematical information than the current one.

Comment: @YCor Now I have a proof that each point of the Golomb space is fixed by any homeomorphism, which is much stronger than just fixing 1. I have posted this proof to arXiv and am waiting (48 hours) till it will appear in order to add the link. The proof is 5 pages long and consists of 12 relatively short lemmas. In principle I can write down these 12 lemmas in my answer to make a sketch of the proof here.

Comment: @YCor I wrote down the proof (consisting of 10 lemmas).

Comment: Could you edit to clarify "the announced proof of the rigidity of the Golomb space contained a gap"? which announced proof? you wrote this a while ago but now the main question seems to refer to another announced proof.

Comment: @YCor Now I wrote "my proof" instead of "announced proof"