# Countably infinite connected Hausdorff space with the fixed point property

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there an infinite, countable connected $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ such that $(X,\tau)$ has the fixed point property? (This means that for every continuous map $f:X\to X$ there is $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = x$.)

Comment: I'd have tried with the Golomb space minus some lacunary subset (maybe $\{n!:n\ge 1\}$ is OK). Just to discard those maps $n\mapsto kn$ and remain connected.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit and maybe add this as an answer? Thanks @YCor

Comment: No, because I'm far from a proof. It would require a proof of the fixed point property. I only suspect it holds.

Comment: About continuous self-maps of $\mathbb{G}$, see also  https://mathoverflow.net/a/286575/14094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is such an example.

This is nearly Problem 10705 in **The American Mathematical Monthly**, proposed by D. W. Brown in [**106** #1 (January 1999), p. 67](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589591), where the problem asks for a countably infinite $T_{2}$ example. In an editorial comment following John Cobb's solution in [**107** #4 (April 2000), pp. 375-376](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589200), it is stated that Prabir Roy's lattice space --- [*A countable connected Urysohn space with a dispersion point*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077376386), **Duke Mathematical Journal** 33 #2 (1966), pp. 331-333 --- is an example that is a countable *connected* Urysohn space. For what it's worth, my notes on this problem say that this can be verified by making use of the analog in Roy's space of observations (a) and (b) at the beginning of the proof of the theorem at the bottom of p. 375.