# Is $\mathbb{Q}$ the continuous image of a Golomb-like space, or vice versa?

Tags: gn.general-topology

The set $${\cal B} = \big\{\emptyset\big\}\cup\big\{\{a + bn: n\in\omega\}: a\in\omega, b\in(\omega\setminus\{0\})\big\}$$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\omega$. Is there a surjective continuous map from $\mathbb{Q}$ with the Euclidean topology onto $(\omega,\tau)$, or the other way round, or in neither direction?

**Note.** These two spaces are not homeomorphic, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is homogeneous, and $(\omega,\tau)$ [is not](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285557/is-the-golomb-countable-connected-space-topologically-rigid).

Comment: And this is not the definition of Golomb space: in the Golomb space $0$ is excluded, and $a,b$ are coprime.

Comment: $a\mapsto\lfloor a+\sqrt{2}\rfloor$ is a continuous surjection from $\mathbb Q$ to a discrete countable space. Feel free to take it from there.

Comment: Note: this topology is the topology induced by inclusion of $\omega$ (the natural numbers) into $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ (the profinite completion of $\mathbf{Z}$). So this topology is actually homeomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}$, and is far from "Golomb-like", much more standard. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355779/showing-mathbbq-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbbq2/1642728#1642728 for this topological characterization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your topology is by definition the profinite topology of $\mathbf{Z}$, restricted to the nonnegative numbers $\mathbf{N}$. Hence it's a nonempty countable metrizable space. By a classical theorem of Sierpiński ([Dasgupta - Countable metric spaces without isolated points](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm), [pdf](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf)), this implies that it is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}$, in contradiction with your claim.

Golomb's space is defined as yours, but restricting to positive numbers and to coprime arithmetic progressions: precisely this subtlety drastically changes the topology (which is then connected—removing 0 is necessary to have it Hausdorff).